# Why are vector components themselves not vectors?

Tags: vectors

My introductory physics textbook, *Young & Freedman, University Physics with Modern Physics (13th Ed)*, makes the following claim on page 14:

> Caution: Components are not vectors - The components $A_x$ and $A_y$ of a vector $\vec{A}$ are just numbers; they are *not* vectors themselves. This is why we print the symbols for components  in light italic type with *no* arrow on top instead of in boldface italic with a arrow, which is reserved for vectors.

To me however, it seems that the components of any vector $\vec{A}$ are just vectors with pure x, y, or z directions, and $\vec{A}$ is simply the vector sum of those components.

Can anyone explain why this is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector $\vec{A}$ can be decomposed as
$$\vec{A} = A_x \hat{x} + A_y \hat{y} + A_z \hat{z}.$$
Indeed, $A_x \hat{x}$ is a vector. But it's not a "vector component" as the term is usually used, $A_x$ is.